# Удалить объект в массиве по свойству

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача - удалить объект со свойством name: 'груша' из массива в том случае, если он там есть.
Как это можно сделать при помощи javascript/jQuery?

Comment: 1) `findIndex()`; 2) `splice()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У массивов есть метод `filter`. Он в качестве аргумента получает функцию, которая должна что-то проверить и вернуть true или false. В зависимости от ответа этой функции - элемент останется или удалится:

```js
let arr = [
  {name: "груша", cost: 50},
  {name: "велосипед", cost: 5000},
  {name: "бобер", cost: 100500},
];

function removeElementByName(arr, name){
  return arr.filter( e => e.name !== name );
  //  function(e){ return e.name !== name; } — то же самое
}

console.log( removeElementByName(arr, "груша") );
```

При этом, сам исходный массив не меняется. Функция только возвращает отфильтрованный кусок. Чтобы изменить массив, нужно записать `arr = removeElementByName(arr, "груша")`;